# inverse queue algorithm to improve

Tags: java

I want to inverse queue, how can I improve this algorithm
Then I want to inverse this queue by method. Can I just new an stack object in queue's method to inverse?Or I can try another algorithm to improve this algorithm?

````
package test;
import java.util.*;
public class inverse {

public static void main(String[] args) {

  Queue q=new Queue();//create a queue Intege
  Stack<Integer> s=new Stack<>();//create a stack Intege
  q.enqueue(3);//enqueue Intege
  q.enqueue(4);//enqueue Intege
  q.enqueue(5);//enqueue Intege
  while(!q.isEmpty())s.add(q.dequeue());//dequeue to stack Intege
  Queue nq=new Queue();//create a new queue Intege
  while(!s.isEmpty())nq.enqueue(s.pop());//enqueue from stack Intege
  while(!nq.isEmpty())System.out.println(nq.dequeue());//print nq Intege
 }

}
class Queue{
 private node first;
 private node last;
 private int N;
 class node{
  int item;
  node next;
 }
 public boolean isEmpty() {return first==null;}//empty Intege
 public int size() {return N;}
 public void enqueue(int item) {//enqueue Intege
  node oldlast=last;//new node Intege
  last=new node();
  last.item=item;
  last.next=null;
  if(isEmpty())first=last;
  else oldlast.next=last;
  N++;
 }
 public int dequeue() {//dequeue Intege
  int item=first.item;
  first=first.next;
  if(isEmpty())last=null;//empty Intege
  N--;
  return item;
 }
}
```
````

Comment: One of the options is to have a double-linked queue (i.e. add `prev` into the node), so you could traverse a queue in both directions.

Comment: Note that there are implementations in the default libraries for things like that.